# Jenkins job got stuck after 30-40 minutes while passing results to a 3rd party server

Tags: jenkins

In my Jenkins setup, we have a 6 hour long test suite running on a separate agent machine.
After each test execution it will bundle all the results with a screenshot (bundle everything as a JSON) and send it to a 3rd party reporting server as an API call.

But sometimes after 30 -40 minutes of execution, the Jenkins job will get stuck where it's sending JSON data to a 3rd party server.

At the same time if I do the same API call using postman, it works fine, but through Jenkins it's not sending properly.

This might be due to some network policy or restriction or due to a security scanner, but how am I going to resolve it.

Where should I start?

*I'm 100% sure it's not about the resource issue.
There is no any specific pattern on which test case is stuck.
Jenkins agent also up and running.*

Comment: are you closing the process after sending the request

Comment: No,Im not @PDHide

Comment: you should jenkisn remains open if any pending process are left behind like a server spawn from that jenkins job etc

Comment: Are you sure that you are sending the same request via Postman and Jenkins? Could - for example - the user-agent headers be different? Can the source IP be a difference? Is it possible that network traffic from your Jenkins is blocked/filtered? I would try to debug the network traffic from Jenkins to the API. Do you have a way to see what requests comes in to your API? That's where I would start.

Comment: May be this issue occurring because of the system idle time on EC2 instance

Comment: No ,this is nothing to do with system idle time on EC2 instance ,I can confirm it.